# Why does Mozilla Firefox 3.5 freezes?

Tags: firefox

I recently upgraded Firefox from 3.0 to 3.5. Since then I have a lot of trouble running this app. It freezes after 1 sec and stops responding to any commands.

How can I make it work again? If there's no known fix for it, where can I still download the older 3.0 version?

Answer (score 1):

Old Version: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [Frans Bouma's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2009/07/09/the-firefox-3-5-fiasco.aspx) it´s a bug/feature in the random number generator of the Network Security System (NSS) used by FF3.5. In a few words: NSS reads the files in the system temp folder to use as seeds for the randomization.

Comment: that's horrifying, so you're saying a malicious program could put a bunch of 0x0000 null-files in the temp folder to dictate NSS's rng seeds?

Comment: @hanshenrik yes. bad engineering decision. unfortunately happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all your add-ins first.  If it still doesn't work, go with an older version using the link from Zoredache.

Comment: The very annoying thing is that now, Firefox 3.0 has the exact same symptoms. It freezes after 2s. Can it be that the random generator component remained installed the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with a different profile? If you start firefox with the argument "-p", the profile manager pops up. You can create a new profile there and use that profile to see if it works. If it does, it means that your previous profile was corrupted in some way.